# How can i delegate a subdomain to a new Zone on a local DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

i'am a trainee in IT in my second year and i'am actually building a windows server/client test enviroment.

Actually i want to build an active directory with a real subdomain. The Domain is hosted by my service providers DNS server.

My Testlab looking like this:

[Testlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obbtr.png)

I read a lot of microsoft documentation about DNS and know the basics of it.

Now i want to set up a DNS Server Managing a new Zone for the subdomain ad.meinedomain.com . The subdomain for my test Active directory.

The Microsoft documentation tells me that Records should be set like this:

[Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPJ6O.png)

But i don't know how to set the A record because the DNS Server has a private IP Address.

Can you tell me how i can delegate the subdomain to a new zone on a private DNS Server?

Comment: DNS doesn't care about RFC1918-addresses or not. For the purpose of DNS, an IP is an IP. If it's globally routable is *your* problem, and not something DNS will ever care about.

Comment: Ok but my question was more or less how can i delegate the subdomain to my privat dns server anyway. Is there any way? Or can i just say. I dont care i give my local DNS Server the subdomain anyway. What will happen? Is this possible? Sry i'am complete new about this topic?

Comment: Do your test lab really require the names to be resolvable on the Internet?

Comment: actually i don't know. Later i want to connect it to azure as you see it on the picture. And I'm doing this for my first time. So I don't know what the impact is later, when i connect to azure.

Comment: It's still off topic on server fault. We don't do learning materials or homelabs.

Comment: I don't think so, because its simply building a small company client/server windows  infrastructure. And i have ask a question about how to do so. The fact that you don't know the answer doesn't make it offtopic

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delegate the sub-domain to your internal servers. Your public DNS servers and your private DNS servers don't know about each other.

Your public DNS servers will be authoritative for the meinedomain.com domain and your private DNS servers will be authoritative for the ad.meinedomain.com domain.

The only potential issue is if you use the ad.meinedomain.com in your public DNS zone. In that case your internal AD clients will have trouble resolving DNS records in the public DNS zone for ad.meinedomain.com.

Comment: Thx for the answer I rty it out :))

Comment: I'm rly not sure about that because in Microsoft Documentation they say: When an Active Directory domain is created, a DNS delegation entry must exist in the DNS zone that is the parent of the zone supporting the Active Directory domain.

Comment: I now found it out. Its possible to not have DNS delegation in the parent Zone. But if you do so all clients need to use the local dns server. Just if someone have the same question